# Entering text into tinymce using webdriver, ruby and variables

Tags: ruby, parameters, tinymce, webdriver

I'm using webdriver and Ruby...

So I was able to write text into a tinymce field using the script below.  However on the last line, driver.execute...  I would like to change the static value 'bob' to be the value of the variable being passed, parValue.  I've tried few modifications to the driver.execute_script line, but I continue to get errors.  In other words, I don't know javascript and I am unable to find a way to do this.

I've tried replacing the code and use sendkeys, but that does not print anything to my tinymce box.  Is there a way to use the value being passed in from parValue and replace 'bob'?

```
def enterValues(driver,parField,parValue)
  tinymce_frame = driver.find_element(:id => parField)
  driver.switch_to.default_content
  driver.switch_to.frame(tinymce_frame)     
  editor_body = driver.find_element(:tag_name => 'body')
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'bob'", editor_body)

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems kind of simple so I'm worried I might be misunderstanding but you could use ruby's string interpolation to replace `bob` with `parvalue`:

```
def enterValues(driver,parField,parValue)
  tinymce_frame = driver.find_element(:id => parField)
  driver.switch_to.default_content
  driver.switch_to.frame(tinymce_frame)     
  editor_body = driver.find_element(:tag_name => 'body')
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML = '#{parValue}'", editor_body)

end
```

Comment: What you said about being simple and misunderstanding what I needed, no, you're right with the code.  For the life of me I tried every syntax possible to parametrize the static text 'bob' and I was unable to do it.  So thank you,  the #{} is what I was not doing.  I grew up using cobol and C.  I'm trying to catch up.

Comment: another solution would've been `"arguments[0].innerHTML = '"+ parValue + "'"`